Enviar valor dependiendo de URL
Me gustaría enviar un valor a una etiqueta tipo select dependiendo del URL.
 Tengo esta URL: ejemplo.com/la-manzana-es-verde
dentro de ese URL existirá un formulario en el cual se enviarán varios datos, entre ellos un select oculto con valores: verde, rojo, morado.
Intento generar un js para que al momento de enviar el formulario en el select oculto se envié (sin que el usuario lo tenga que seleccionar) el valor verde ya que en el url dice que la manzana es verde.

¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes? Donde está el Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable de lo que has hecho y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen) que se menciona en el [tour] y en [ask]

Por lo que entendí, la dirección tomará una información y la añadirá al select.
En caso de no haber interpretado de forma incorrecta, la base puede ser.
Usa como referencia esta w3schools
Este fragmento tomará la URL completa
window.location.href

Y el uso del método split() divide una cadena en una lista ordenada de subcadenas.
Esta es una forma de resolverlo: usar createElement en las opciones del select añadiendo al elemento padre un elemento hijo y luego recuperar las options del select con la información añadida.


const url = window.location.href;

const partes = url.split('/');
const ultimaParte = partes[partes.length - 1];

const parteColor = ultimaParte.split('-');
const colorDeLaManzana = parteColor[parteColor.length - 1];

let campoSeleccion = document.getElementById("options");
let nuevaOpcion = document.createElement("option");
nuevaOpcion.text = colorDeLaManzana;
campoSeleccion.add(nuevaOpcion);

campoSeleccion.addEventListener("change", function() { 
    var indiceSeleccionado = campoSeleccion.options.selectedIndex;
    var valorSeleccionado = campoSeleccion.options[indiceSeleccionado].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("opcion_seleccionada").innerHTML = valorSeleccionado;
});
  <form>
    <select id="options">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione una opción</option>
      <option value="1">opción 1</option>
     </select>
  <p id="opcion_seleccionada"></p>
</form>



Ahora en la URL de ejemplo informada: ejemplo.com/la-manzana-es-verde
específicamente verde será adicionada al option.

Deja que el usuario sepa hacer bien su pregunta primero. No hay nada de esfuerzo en esta pregunta
